# Stiffness matrix issue

Tags: matrix-elements

Good day All,
while trying to solve this exercice[image]

I was puzzeld by the solution approach
indeed, they use the symmetry of the structure, they have made a cut on the hinge where the force F is applied (the force F has been divided by 2 for the symmetry reason), and ONLY replace it with a HORIZONTAL REACTION!!!!
according to my basic understanding, when we do a cut in a hinge we replace it with two reactions HORIZONTAL and VERTICAL!
[image]
Any help would be highly appreciated !
Thanks